# Extract href value from html string using QRegExp

Tags: html, regex, qt, qregexp

I am downloading a web page and I am trying to extract some values from it.

The places of the page that I am interested in are of this type:

```
<a data-track=\"something\" href=\"someurl\" title=\"Heaven\"><img src=\"somesource.jpg\" /></a>
```

and I need to extract the href (someurl) value. Note that there are multiple entries like the one above in the HTML string that I have and thus I will use a list to store all the URLs that I extract from the string.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
QString html_str=myfile();
QRegExp regex("<a data-track\\=\"something\" href\\=\".*(?=\" title)");
if(regex.indexIn(html_str) != -1){
    QStringList list;
    QString str;
    list = regex.capturedTexts();
    foreach(str,list)
        qDebug() << str.remove("<a data-track=\"something\" href=\"");
}
```

With the above code I get only one occurrence (`list.count() == 1`) which contains the whole HTML string from the first occurrence of `someurl` till the end of the file, without the `<a data-track="something" href=""` in it, which have all been removed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Use `QtWebKit`. Don't parse html using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this: (make sure you double check your regex)

```
QRegExp regex("<a data-track=\"something\" href=\".*(?=\" title)");

if (regex.indexIn(html_str) != -1) qDebug() << html_str.cap().remove(<a data-track=\"something\" href=\");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to control the position of the "html_str"

```
pos = regex.indexIn(htmlContent);    // get the first position
while(pos = regex.indexIn(htmlContent, pos) != -1){    // continue next
    QStringList list;
    list = regex.capturedTexts();
    foreach(QString url, list) {
        // do something
    }
    pos += regex.matchedLength();
}
```